# although doesn't set output color to second output color variable in fragment shader, it still set color to second color output variable (opengl)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

i'm making some postprocessing work.

when i tried rendering to framebuffer having two color texture,
i didn't wanna set output color to second ouput color variable, just wanna set to first variable,
but shader still set internally first output color variable to second output color variable

```
Render Loop

BindFrameBuffer();
unsigned int a[2] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, a);
RenderSomthing();!!!
```

```
Fragment shader

#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor; 
//layout (location = 1) out vec4 BloomColor; 

void main()
{
   FragColor = vec4(1.0);
   //BloomColor= vec4(1.0); // i dont wanna draw on second color output variable
}
```

i dont wanna touch second output color variable, i wanna just let it have cleared color

shader still set internally first output color variable to second output color variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to write in one color attachment of the framebuffer, you only need to specify one drawing buffer before drawing the geometry:

```cpp
unsigned int a[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, a);
RenderSomthing();
```

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 17.4.1 Selecting Buffers for Writing](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> If a fragment shader writes to a user-defined output variable, DrawBuffers
> specifies a set of draw buffers into which each of the multiple output colors defined by these variables are separately written. If a fragment shader writes to no
> user-defined output variables, the values of the fragment colors following shader
> execution are undefined, and may differ for each fragment color. If some, but not
> all user-defined output variables are written, the values of fragment colors corresponding to unwritten variables are similarly undefined.

---

One option to write to the buffers individual, is t o use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending#Source.2C_Destination.2C_and_the_buffer). Use [`glBlendFunci`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) or [`glBlendFuncSeparate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFuncSeparate.xhtml) to individually specify the blending function for a draw buffer.

e.g. disable writing to to draw buffer with index 1:

```cpp
glBlendFunci(1, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE);
```

Comment: nop. i wanna write to 2 color attachment of framebuffer, but on specific fragment shader i wanna write to only first color attachment, so i coded setting to only first output color variable, but in internally opengl(?? maybe) set first out variable to second variable

Comment: @hour30000 *" but on specific fragment shader i wanna write to only first color attachment,"* - So you need to switch the draw buffer before you draw something with this specific shader. Or use blending. See the answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Isn't there way draw to only first color attachment at state that glDrawBuffers(2,  { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 }... i thought if i set color only to layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor, not layout (location = 1) out vec4 BloomColor, shader draw only to First color buffer. because it means that shader set color to first color attachment and doesn't draw anything to second color attachment

Comment: @hour30000 No. Read the answer. What's wrong with switching the draw buffers? You also switch the shader.

Comment: i know switching the draw buffer works.. but in my rendering engine it's a little hard to change shader, draw buffers every time when draw so many objects. so i wonder is it posibble to draw just one buffer of two without changing drarwbuffer state, shader